# Sorting function returns wrong object type on C++17

Tags: c++, list, gcc, lambda, c++17

For some reason when I try to compile the following code with the -std=c++17 flag I get the following error.

The code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

std::list<int> partition(std::list<int>::const_iterator &&begin,
                         std::list<int>::const_iterator &&end,
                         std::function<bool(int)> predicate) {
  std::list<int> result;
  while (begin != end) {
    if (predicate(*begin)) {
      result.push_front(*begin);
    } else {
      result.push_back(*begin);
    }
    begin++;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::list<int> numbers{15, 20, 25, -10, -75, 100, -255, 430, 200};

  std::cout << "Original list:" << std::endl;
  for (int &e : numbers) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

  std::cout << "[](int num) { return !(num % 2); }" << std::endl;
  std::list<int> result = partition(numbers.cbegin(), numbers.cend(), [](int num) { return !(num % 2); });
  for (int &e : result) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:31:36: error: conversion from ‘std::_List_const_iterator<int>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::list<int>’ requested
   31 |   std::list<int> result = partition(numbers.cbegin(), numbers.cend(),
      |                           ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   32 |                                     [](int num) { return !(num % 2); });
      |                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

For some reason when I create a std::function<bool(int)> and store the lambda inside it, then pass the function pointer I don't get this error

Code that works:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

std::list<int> partition(std::list<int>::const_iterator &&begin,
                         std::list<int>::const_iterator &&end,
                         std::function<bool(int)> predicate) {
  std::list<int> result;
  while (begin != end) {
    if (predicate(*begin)) {
      result.push_front(*begin);
    } else {
      result.push_back(*begin);
    }
    begin++;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::list<int> numbers{15, 20, 25, -10, -75, 100, -255, 430, 200};

  std::cout << "Original list:" << std::endl;
  for (int &e : numbers) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

  std::cout << "[](int num) { return !(num % 2); }" << std::endl;
  std::function<bool(int)> func = [](int num) { return !(num % 2); };
  std::list<int> result = partition(numbers.cbegin(), numbers.cend(), func);
  for (int &e : result) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know the reason for this behavior? When I compile without the std flag, or when I compile on Windows I don't get that error. GCC version 10.2., on Arch Linux.

Comment: The problem is that ADL is kicking in and finding `std::partition` by mistake. If you call your function `xpartition`, then it works fine again.

Comment: Didn't know that something like ADL exists till now. I was suspicious that it might be the name of the function. Thanks for helping me out with this. I was already losing hope.

Comment: The clue is in this part of the error message: " required from '_BIter **std::partition**(_BIter, _BIter, _Predicate) [with _BIter = std::_List_const_iterator<int>; _Predicate = main()::<lambda(int)>]'" - it's reporting a problem with getting the call to `std::partition` to work.

Comment: Try to use `auto` for type deduction like `auto result = partition(...)`.

Comment: @4xy that would just make the problem less obvious. The problem is that I named my function partiton not knowing that there is an actual STL  function std::partition with the exact same signature. I was just using the names that our university provided but I guess they uploaded the homework tasks without even checking...

Answer (score 0):

The partition function returns an iterator!

Try this:

```
std::list<int>::iterator result = partition(numbers.cbegin(), numbers.cend(), [](int num) { return !(num % 2); });
```

Comment: Sorry! I've just seen that partition is a function of yours...
I thought you were using the std::partition

Comment: The function that I made should return a list instead of a list iterator, the problem is that there was a name conflict with my functions and STL functions. Raymond already solved my problem in the comment section, but definitely thanks for helping me out!